# Specify a different type for some keys of a dictionary in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do something like that in Typescript :

```
type A = 'stuff'
type B = {
  [x: string]: {
    active?: {
      [name: string] : A
    }
    [name: string] : A
  }
}
```

But I get : `Property 'active' of type '{ [name: string]: A; } | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'A'.`

What I understand is that `active` is also recognized as a member of [name: string]. Is there aanything I can do to precise that `active` might contain something different from the other keys?

I hope this is not a duplicate, I had a hard time finding the good way to describe the problem in Google.

** Update: **

The following code fail with Typescript

```js
type ImageName = 'test'
type IconEntry = { [name: string]: ImageName }
type Icons = {
  [namespace: string]: IconEntry & {
    active?: IconEntry;
  };
}

const icons: Icons = {
  buttons: {
    switch: 'test',
    active: {
      switch: 'test'
    }
  }
}
```

```js
Type '{ switch: "test"; active: { switch: "test"; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IconEntry & { active?: IconEntry | undefined; }'.
  Type '{ switch: "test"; active: { switch: "test"; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IconEntry'.
    Property 'active' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type '{ switch: "test"; }' is not assignable to type '"test"'.(2322)
input.ts(4, 3): The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

Answer (score 3):

The only difference I see in `active` is that it's `A | undefined` instead of just `A`. You can define that with an [*intersection type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
type A = "stuff";
type B = {
  [x: string]: {[name: string] : A} & {active?: A}
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

With that, assuming you have `let b: B`, then `b["x"].active` will have the type `"stuff" | undefined` and `b["x"].foo` will have the type `"stuff"`.

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBEBnYBXAZppBuAUKJFAEIJQDe+UNUA2gB4BcUaATgJYB2A5gLosKdLgEMAthBbtu-KCxgBfKADJKIgMbAOANwgB+eQvwB6Y1EBIRJavXLAPXsPHT5y5f4FBfABMI6gDYibNB+EMBQAEYsJJ6mUAASAPa6bFDAABYQKNDACawQ2RkcKUSZ+OF0SAxIfAB0Glq6uLS0sQAq4JLIaFg4UAA+UOhcPpjcEF5lFVW1mAkJTc3NbR0sqBjYSPhAA)

The same approach works if you want `active` to have a completely different type, unrelated to `A`:

```
type A = "stuff";
type A1 = "other stuff";
type B = {
    [x: string]: { [name: string]: A } & { active?: A1 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! active is actually a dictionary of A instead of just A. I'm trying this right away

Comment: Weird. Sorry, I don't know what to do with the revised version. I would have thought what you did worked.